# AVR ATMEGA328p Blinking Example

Tags: avr, atmega

I wanted to test a simple blinking script on my ATMEGA328p. The breadboard setup (tested and works fine). But the LED does not blink. I probed the voltages across the board and they are showing up with 5V as expected. The avrdude response is also expected. Just the LED does not blink. I switched the chip too, but this doesn't have any effect. Do you have any ideas?

I also measured the LED pin but there is 0V on the pin and I would expect it changing to 5V with the code provided.

[image]

**code.c**

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
  DDRB = 0b00000001;

  while (1) {
    PORTB = 0b00000001;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I created a compile script:

**compile**

```
#!/bin/bash
avr-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -c code.c
avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o code.elf code.o
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex code.elf code.hex
avr-size --format=avr --mcu=atmega328p code.elf
```

and flashed file to the ATMEGA

```
avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U flash:w:code.hex
```

the AVRDUDE output:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Sep 21 2018 at 19:15:33
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/usr/local/Cellar/avrdude/6.3_1/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/sebastianscharf/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: 020:012
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D9
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: reading input file "code.hex"
avrdude: input file code.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (178 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.29s

avrdude: 178 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against code.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file code.hex:
avrdude: input file code.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file code.hex contains 178 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.21s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 178 bytes of flash verified

avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D9
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:D9, L:62)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: `The breadboard setup (tested and works fine)` .... what does this actually mean? .....

Comment: Did you program the oscillator? Normally it runs at 1MHz if you dont change the fuses.

Comment: @jsotola: it seems to me that the geen LED is connected to PB0. sesc360: But why is there no resistor in series with it?

Comment: @jsotola Yes you are right. I forgot that resistor too.

Comment: @jsotola I mean i measured voltages across the board and tested if the setup itself works. maybe a bit unclear what I wrote

Comment: @jsotola did I miss anything in my code? I thought I have set PB0 as output pin.

Comment: Turns out.. the breadboard is faulty and has a broken connector line

Comment: @sesc360 if the issue was in fact a breadboard connectivity one, and you have solved the problem, then that is the answer which resolves your question.  You should post it as an answer and accept it once the self-answer timer expires, otherwise the question will continue to show as unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

By accident I found out when measuring with the multimeter that the breadboard had a connectivity issue, by accidently touching the LED and the PB0 pin. Now changed the breadboard and all works. Thanks everyone.